# ASP Core Azure Active Directory - Get First and Last Name

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

I created an Azure Active Directory Application and applied the code from the following tutorial to enable login: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-openidconnect-aspnetcore/

After login the following returns my email adress:

```
Console.WriteLine(User.Identity.Name)
```

How would i retreive the First and Last Name of this user?

Comment: Have you tried using Graph API?

Comment: OpenId scope returns first name and last name claims in token. Should be able to extract from claims principal after authN

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found it:

```
var fn = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.GivenName).Value;
var ln = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Surname).Value;
System.Console.WriteLine("me :" + fn + " " + ln );
```

Answer (score 1):

I use this, this gets you the first and last name together -

```
var name = claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "name")?.Value;
```